# Fortran execute_command_line does not return result

Tags: fortran

I need to create a file in fortran and then read the data in the file.

```
call execute_command_line('pwd > workdir.dat')

open(unit=10, file='workdir.dat', status='replace', IOSTAT=open_stat)
    if (open_stat /= 0) stop "Reading workdir.dat file Error"
    read(10,"(A)") workdir
close(10)
```

However, `workdir.dat` is empty when I try to open it, giving me serious open error. It seems that the system only flush the content of `workdir.dat` to the file at the end of the program. How do I make sure `workdir.dat` is ready to use before `open` ?

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem --- status `old` should be used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the mistake was pointed out in comments and we don't want it sitting on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `open` statement includes the clause `status=replace` which, in effect, tells the run time system that to discard the file's contents and write them anew.  To be precise, the language standard states wrt to the `status` specifier on an `open` statement:

> If REPLACE is specified and the file does exist, the file is deleted,
>   a new file is created with the same name, and the status is changed to
>   OLD.

Change the clause to `status=old` which is the correct specification for this case.